# CSS: Selected Elements Not Responding As They Should

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to build a chessboard, using HTML tables and CSS. I have managed to do the "hard" part of having the alternating tiles but, the surrounding cells (A, B, C, ...) should be a completely different colour.

However, when I select them and set a different colour, they do not work as they should. All they do is darken.
[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
table{
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
tr{
    height: 75px;
}
tr:first-child, tr:last-child{
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black!important;
}
td:first-child, td:last-child{
    width: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black!important;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){
    background: rgba(104, 42, 0, 0.863);
  }
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd){
    background: rgba(148, 67, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td><img src="rook-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="knight-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="bishop-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="king-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="queen-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="bishop-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="knight-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="rook-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><img src="rook-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="knight-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="bishop-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="king-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="queen-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="bishop-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="knight-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td><img src="rook-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Thank you for taking the time to help. Have a great rest of the day!

Comment: Your HTML code ? And what do you mean by "surrounding part" ? The line which has 'A, B ,C, D...' written is your surrounding part?

Comment: I have made the needed edit to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always give a class to to your surrounding row. and apply css to override

Like I have given class `surrounding` to that row

And added following CSS

```
tr.surrounding td:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgba(256, 0, 0, 0.863);
  }
tr.surrounding td:nth-child(odd) {
    background: rgba(0, 256, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```css
table{
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 40px;
}
tr{
    height: 75px;
}
tr:first-child, tr:last-child{
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black!important;
}
td:first-child, td:last-child{
    width: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black!important;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){
    background: rgba(104, 42, 0, 0.863);
  }
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd){
    background: rgba(148, 67, 0, 0.5);
}

tr.surrounding td:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgba(256, 0, 0, 0.863);
  }
tr.surrounding td:nth-child(odd) {
    background: rgba(0, 256, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="surrounding">
    <td></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td><img src="rook-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="king-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="queen-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="rook-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><img src="rook-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="king-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="queen-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="rook-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="surrounding">
    <td></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting all `<td>` in all `<tr>` and applying background with alpha value, So when you change the color of `<tr>` it looks like it's getting darker or lighter.

What you need to do is skip the first and last `<tr>` Like this:

```
tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

And skip the first and last `<td>` in every `<tr>` Like this:

```
td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

---

This is hat you had:

```
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even)
```

This is the new:

```
tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(even)
```

Not complicated at all, But difficult to read. Use of classes is a must here.

```css
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 80px;
}

tr {
  height: 75px;
}

tr:first-child,
tr:last-child {
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange !important;
}

td:first-child,
td:last-child {
  width: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange !important;
}

tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(even),
tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(odd) td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(104, 42, 0, 0.863);
}

tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(odd) td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(even),
tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(148, 67, 0, 0.32);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td><img src="rook-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="king-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="queen-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="rook-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-b.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="pawn-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><img src="rook-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="king-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="queen-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="bishop-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="knight-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td><img src="rook-w.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```